# Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS) in Entity Framework by connection string

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I try to enable MARS(Multiple Active Result Sets) in ASP .NET MVC 5 web applications which uses Entity Framework.

I tried to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=AppDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but I get this:

[image]

This is my `Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=AppDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
   <!-- <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Migrations.Configuration, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11....Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="Syste...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MultipleActiveResultSets is not an attribute.Put it in the connectionString

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DbName;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"
```